# Facebook permission to check user's post existence?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

What is the minimum facebook permission required to check if a user's post still exits in his wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be `user_status`.

`read_stream` would also be a possibility, but it would get you access to friend posts too and it will most likely not get approved by Facebook.

But keep in mind that incentivizing posts is not allowed, so there is most likely no serious application for checking if a user post still exists. Meaning, you may not even get `user_status` approved.